# /opt/bitnami/scripts/libkafka.sh: line 364: arr[2]: unbound variable

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am not so experienced in Kafka, I am to deploy it in my Kubernetes but it is throwing an error. I am sending my artifact. Please could you know how to solve it?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: event-bus-svc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: event-bus-svc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: event-bus-svc
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: event-bus-svc
          image: bitnami/kafka:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID
              value: "0"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES
              value: "controller,broker"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS
              value: "//kafka:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
              value: "CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS
              value: "0@kafka:9093"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES
              value: "CONTROLLER"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: "PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: event-bus-clusterip-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: event-bus-svc
  ports:
    - name: event-bus-src
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
```

Error

/opt/bitnami/scripts/libkafka.sh: line 364: arr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZVaH.png): unbound variable

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] your container to include the YAML file and error message in plain text, not rendered to images?  Are you writing any code of your own, or just trying to deploy the Bitnami Kafka images into your cluster?

Comment: 1) You should open a github issue against the bitnami/containers github repo, if you expected it to work by following their docs 2) You should not use "latest" tags, but instead 3.5 release, for example. 3) Why bitnami instead of https://strimzi.io, especially if you're "not experienced with Kafka", and therefore may have issues managing it on your own?

Comment: Thanks, I will open an issue in their repository, I changed the last for the old versions and I am facing the same issue. About not experience, I believe it is not a hard challenge. Thanks

Comment: You need more than a Deployment and Service to correctly run Kafka in Kubernetes. Specifically, you should be using a StatefulSet, not a Deployment. You'll also need PersistentVolumes if you don't want to lose data when the pod restarts. Using an operator like Strimzi does configure that for you

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I appreciate it and I will ensure to add it to my Kafka design.

Answer (score 0):

Your KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS value is missing a protocol for port 9092, such as PLAINTEXT://

If you want to use the bitnami images, I'd at least recommend you use Helm, rather than write out the resources manually

Comment: I added PLAINTEXT and the error was not solved.